# How to implement Data model using swift? (java -> swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, model-view-controller, model

in Java the model looks like this:

```
public class Model {

private String nameLast = "";
private String nameFirst = "";
private String namePrefix = "";
private String nameSecond = "";
private String nameNick = "";
private String nameSuffix = "";

Model() {

}

public Model(String nameFirst, String nameSecond, String nameLast, String namePrefix, String nameSuffix, String nameNick) {
    this.nameFirst = nameFirst;
    this.nameSecond = nameSecond;
    this.nameLast = nameLast;
    this.namePrefix = namePrefix;
    this.nameSuffix = nameSuffix;
    this.nameNick = nameNick;
}

public String getNameLast() {
    return nameLast;
}

public void setNameLast(String nameLast) {
    this.nameLast = nameLast;
}

public String getNameFirst() {
    return nameFirst;
}

public void setNameFirst(String nameFirst) {
    this.nameFirst = nameFirst;
}

public String getNamePrefix() {
    return namePrefix;
}

public void setNamePrefix(String namePrefix) {
    this.namePrefix = namePrefix;
}
....
}
```

In Swift there is no access control (private/public) and the setter/getters are only for computed properties.
How should I implement this in swift?
Should I use a struct?
Perhaps I have to use willSet and didSet - I need your help ;)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

Comment: You don't need getters and setters if you are not doing anything with them. In Swift you don't have a property and an associated variable, it's all the same, just use a stored property and it is like you already have the getter and setter. "Swift unifies these concepts into a single property declaration."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it really simple in Swift. There are many similar parts in Swift.

```
class Model : NSObject{

    var nameFirst = ""
    var nameSecond = ""
    var nameLast = ""

    init(nameFirst:String, nameSecond:String, nameLast:String){
        self.nameFirst = nameFirst
        self.nameSecond = nameSecond
        self.nameLast = nameLast
    }


}
```

Then, instead of using a get or a set method, you can simply use the variable to set and get the values of the variable:

```
var mod = Model(nameFirst: "hey", nameSecond: "what's", nameLast: "up")
println(mod.nameLast)
```

While `didSet` and `willSet` are useful for counting, how many times a method was set, you don't need it in this case. Also in your case you dont need to set `get` for these variables like that:

```
var value : Int {
    get { return 10 }
}
```